# Save a blob object with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, blob

I have a data uri which I want to upload to the server and store it as a paperclip image attachment. So I used the info on this [link](http://rohitrox.github.io/2013/07/19/canvas-images-and-rails/) to convert the data uri into a blob and then used FormData to upload it to the server.
My coffeescript file looks like this

```
dataURLtoBlob = (dataURL) ->
  binary = atob dataURL.split(',')[1]
  array = []
  i = 0
  while i < binary.length
    array.push binary.charCodeAt(i)
    i++
  return new Blob [new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/png'}

file = dataURLtoBlob(imageSrc)
fd = new FormData()
fd.append "image", file
$.ajax({
   url: "/posts",
   type: "POST",
   data: fd,
   processData: false,
   contentType: false,
});
```

And this is the create action in my controller

```
image = params[:image]
name = SecureRandom.hex + "png"
File.open("#{Rails.root}/public/uploads/#{name}", 'wb') do |f|
  f.write(image.read)
end
```

This works perfectly for storing the image on the server. But how do I integrate it with paperclip, i.e. to generate thumbnails, urls for these images? Thanks in advance.

Comment: yup, cropbox blob. ill have exact the same question now. i'll let you know if i fixed it.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/WizardOfOgz/1012107 here we go. working good.

Answer (score 0):

The same thing comes my mind.

It might be better to check the paperclip_database, which is nice to me.

https://github.com/softace/paperclip_database